# Stack corruption detected after reinstalling app on device

Tags: android, stack, corruption

I receive this error after I reinstalled my app on the device. The main problem is that the code wasn't modified till last time i tested on device, so the error comes unexpectedly. The app crashes aleatory, not in the same place. I also mention that the Logcat contains only 2 rows of errors, without throwing PauseGC or Main errors.

```
10-03 15:03:19.196: A/libc(28568): stack corruption detected
10-03 15:03:19.201: A/libc(28568): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00006f98 (code=-6), thread 28690 (Thread-6865)
```

Answer (score 0):

Random crashes are a sign that you have corrupted some internal state.

Logcat output suggests, you corrupted stack. Probably with a buffer overflow.

Can you share the code? Or even better, can you create a minimal test case that still exhibits this behaviour?

Can you run the binary with `valgrind` or similar tools?

Is there any dump in /data/log/?